# The fate of Eurodollar futures post LIBOR cessation

Tags: sofr, eurodollars, cme

It's my understanding that 3-month USD LIBOR will continue to set until June 30, 2023.  What will happen to CME (3-month) Eurodollar futures after LIBOR is no longer published?  Will they use fallback logic and cash settle against a 26.161bp spread to SOFR?  And, will the CME continue to list *new* expirations as contracts successively expire?

Thanks!

Comment: There are ED futures now trading w/ expiration dates beyond June 2023. In 2021 the CME announced any Eurodollar exposure where the start date is beyond June 30, 2023, will automatically convert to the corresponding CME SOFR futures plus a fixed spread of 26.161 basis points.

Comment: https://www.cmegroup.com/content/dam/cmegroup/notices/ser/2021/02/SER-8720.pdf and https://www.cmegroup.com/openmarkets/interest-rates/The-Shift-From-Eurodollar-to-SOFR-is-Accelerating.html